How can a task in a subprocess send a message to another participant?
I originally posted another question including this one. But for understandable reasons I was asked to split it up.
So the set up is this: I am Participant 1 and go (process simplified) through a sub process. Within I do nothing, until Participant 1 sends me a message to move on.
But while 'doing nothing' I send a daily message (nothing specific here) to Participant 1.
So I presume that the first (red) version is wrong, as the task must not cross sub process borders directly.
But is the second (blue) one right?
A non interrupting boundary event on the task channels to the eventually throwing end event to the catching boundary event of the sub process which then channels to throwing in direction of Participant 2?
Or what am I missin? - Any ideas appreciated.


